# DotnetOpenAuth RefreshAuthorization blocked 403 Forbidden (12202)

Tags: authentication, iis, asp.net-web-api, dotnetopenauth

I've a DotnetOpenAuth authorization server which works great on my localhost. However after publishing it my refresh access token request is blocked.

The request for a accesstoken, with success

```
POST https://myurl/identity/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic dsjSDLFJKSKLJesww
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: DotNetOpenAuth.Core/4.2.1.13026
Host: myhost
Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 86
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

username=theusername&password=fancypassword&scope=somescope&grant_type=password
```

The refresh request:

```
POST https://myurl/identity/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic dsjSDLFJKSKLJesww
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: DotNetOpenAuth.Core/4.2.1.13026
Host: myhost
Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 272
Expect: 100-continue

refresh_token=_ttH%21IAAAAGiYhlufAaXURH5P2oDOnPYgJx7YhoR33isvZkPPvlyUgQAAAAHoBYyDMLhq1qwGHHH2uGrLoHZli77XHbCnSFJSKLFJ3kl2j3klj2kljKFSJKLSJKL#$k3ljfsklfjl2
```

And the response:

> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> Error Code: 403 Forbidden. The server denied the specified Uniform
>   Resource Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator. (12202)

Any help, guidelines, pointers in any direction, would be very much appriciated!

I changed the url/username/password/scope/base64/refreshtoken for this example.

Comment: What did you set the callback URL in your OAuth settings?

Comment: The callback URL is empty, anything is allowed. But the tokenendpoint is never hit, the call is blocked before it. Also in this scenario the resource-owner-password-credential flow is used, so no callback's are included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their seems to be a setting in the `TMG Forefront - Authentication Delegation` which blocked the request.

> Method used by Forefront TMG to authenticate to the published Web
>   server:
>
> 1. No delegation, and the client cannot authenticate directly
> 2. No delegation, but client may authenticate directly

It was set to option 1 after changing it to 2 the request is no longer blocked!

Comment: In which file can I find these settings?

Comment: Click Start, click All Programs, click Microsoft Forefront TMG, and then click Forefront TMG Management.